# Sort NSArray of NSDictionaries

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, sorting

I have a problem with sorting... I need to sort `NSArray` containing `NSDictionaries`. As an order key I have to use element from the `NSDictionary`.

I was reading a little about sorting `NSArray` but it is not clear to me. 
Could you try help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `NSSortDescriptor` and a keypath. Assuming the key for the dictionary is `key`:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sd = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"key" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sorted = [array sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sd]];
```

Comment: Hm... still don't understand how. See, I have such an array ARRAY: (
        {
        LEVEL = NORMAL;
        NAME = Konrad;
        TIME = 269;
    },
        {
        LEVEL = NORMAL;
        NAME = Konrad;
        TIME = 219;
    },
        {
        LEVEL = NORMAL;
        NAME = Konrad;
        TIME = 196;
    },
        {
        LEVEL = NORMAL;
        NAME = Konrad;
        TIME = 237;
    },
        {
        LEVEL = NORMAL;
        NAME = Konrad;
        TIME = 185;
    }
) The key is TIME.

Comment: Ochh... I see :) Just replaced @"key" with @"TIME" and it works, thanks :)